# File versions of a large number of referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, file, versioning, .net-assembly

My team and I are stuck on a version issue I do not think this has been answered before, so apologies if it has. I'll just talk about file version.

We are working on a project that references a large number of assemblies (50+). These assemblies all have file versions of v.1.5.x.x and so on.

A large change is being made to the project as a whole and the project version number is going to v.2.0.0.0.

However, only minor modifications have been made to each of the referenced assemblies. Usually, the file version of these assemblies would go from v.1.5.x.0 to v.1.5.x.1, and so on.

However, since we are making a large modification to the application, would it make more sense to set the file versions of all these assemblies to v.2.0.0.0?

Looking at the .net assemblies, this seems to be what Microsoft do?

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: If the referenced assemblies are directly part of your project, then yes - keep the versions in sync. If the assemblies can be maintained independently of the project, then keep their versioning separate.